# It's time for a Zend-ectomy, but am I doing it correctly?

Tags: discussion, tags, bump

The [zend](/questions/tagged/zend) tag and I do not see eye to eye.  About 90% of the questions in it really belong in the higher-population [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework), while the rest randomly belong to some of the other various Zend product tags, like [zend-server](/questions/tagged/zend-server).  There is no reason to discuss Zend-the-company on SO, but their products are relevant.

There are "only" 1,300 questions, so I've started the slow and tedious process of properly retagging these into a more useful and accurate tag.  I'll also eventually be petitioning for a blacklist of the tag, as it serves no useful purpose.

Of course, there's a problem.  Each edit I make ends up bumping the question on the front page.  This means that I'm going to end up bumping questions from 2008, which may not be productive.  **Is there a better way to edit tags that doesn't involve bumping ancient, out-of-date questions?**  Or perhaps some useful tool that I'm unaware of, or that I can't access, that *only edits tags without the edited-question bump*?  Unfortunately each question needs human inspection for proper re-tagging, so having it done automatically won't work.

I just don't want to raise these things from the dead so aggressively.  I'm clogging up the front page, and that makes me feel kind of disruptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diamond moderators have the ability to retag without bumping, iirc.  Perhaps that only applies to mass retagging though?

Regardless, such tools are not available to us plebes, and for good reason.  We want such edits to be peer reviewed.

Don't fret too much over it.  The front page is customized for each user now, so they won't see your edits unless they are into php already.  It won't harm anyone, and if people complain they can come here to find out what the deal is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could automate part of the tagging, (not really knowing anything/much about Zend), perhaps questions that *should* be tagged [zend-server](/questions/tagged/zend-server) are regularly tagged with something else kind of unique (just guessing) [server](/questions/tagged/server) which wouldn't be appropriate to [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework)...that may at least reduce the amount that require manual inspection.

Hopefully you get the idea...

Comment: It seems to be a crapshoot.  Only about 10% of the mistags are, for example, [tag:zend] + [tag:frameworks].  I'm currently going through those and moving them over, getting the soft targets out of the way first, as those are *guaranteed* to be about ZF.  Mostly.  One of them so far was actually someone setting up Zend Server CE *and* ZF at the same time...  (e: boo, formatting)

Comment: And I'm now encountering zend, frameworks, zend-framework.  Sigh.  Hopefully a pattern will eventually emerge with regard to Zend Server and company.