# Remove [zend] / merge into [zend-framework]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

*Edit, April 21:* Someone re-created the tag the other day.  I've gone through and re-tagged the afflicted questions once again.  [**Two more votes are needed to approve**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework/synonyms) **the [zend](/questions/tagged/zend) tag as a synonym of [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework)**.  This will prevent the tag from being recreated *again*.

---

*Edit, April 5:* [**Three more votes are needed to approve**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework/synonyms) **the [zend](/questions/tagged/zend) tag as a synonym of [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework)**.

---

I have *completed* the [Zend-ectomy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85115/its-time-for-a-zend-ectomy-but-am-i-doing-it-correctly).  Of the ~1,300 questions tagged [zend](/questions/tagged/zend), 850 of which have now been re-tagged by hand into other specific and correct tags, including [zend-server](/questions/tagged/zend-server), [zend-server-ce](/questions/tagged/zend-server-ce), [zend-studio](/questions/tagged/zend-studio), [zend-debugger](/questions/tagged/zend-debugger), [zend-guard](/questions/tagged/zend-guard), [zend-certification](/questions/tagged/zend-certification) and a partridge in a pear tree.

Oh, and [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework).  Lots and lots of Zend Framework.  As it happens [the remaining ~450 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend) are *all* [also tagged zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework%20zend)*.  While there is a small chance that the standalone Zend tag in those specific questions references something other than Zend Framework, it is highly unlikely.

Therefore, I request that the [zend](/questions/tagged/zend) tag be **completely removed** from all questions.

[Zend Technologies Ltd.](http://www.zend.com/en/) produces multiple products, but they are *rarely* the subject of the tag.  Instead, people call [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) "Zend", and thus frequently end up mis-tagged.  Given this, I would also like to request that the tag become an alias of [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework), as people will surely continue to use it otherwise.  The two tags are effectively synonymous.

<sup>* Except for [that single closed one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453620/32-or-64-bit-for-mac?noredirect=1) at the top, which I am unable to retag.</sup>

---

**Edit, April 4:** Given no response from the SO moderation team, I'm just going to finish up the remaining ~450 questions myself.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with Zend, so what did you want that SO/SU question retagged to?

Comment: @TheLQ, that specific closed question could be retagged to `zend-studio`

Comment: Fixed, http://superuser.com/questions/263317/32-or-64-bit-for-mac

Comment: @TheLQ, unfortunately editing the tags on the migration target doesn't change the tags on the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now all-but-completed the retag.  All that's left is the closed-and-migrated question that can not be edited by mortals.  [**Three more votes are still needed**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework/synonyms) to finish the synonym.

I ended up writing a bookmarklet to assist in this task.  Here it is, should someone find it useful:

```
$('#edit-tags').click();
function dezend() { 
    $('#tagnames').val(
        $('#tagnames').val()
            .replace(/\szend\s/, ' ')
            .replace(/^zend\s/, ' ')
            .replace(/\szend$/, '')
    ); 
}
function savetags() {
    clearTimeout(zendectomy); 
    $('#edit-tags-submit').click();
}
zendectomy = setInterval(
    function() {
        if($('#tagnames').length) { dezend(); savetags(); } 
    },
    250
);
return false;
```

(Yes, I know that I could have written the regex in a more brief fashion -- I'm lazy.)

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, that should happen if someone suggests a synonym for `zend-framework` of `zend`, as [I have just done](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework/synonyms).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, Billy.  I'd forgotten that functionality was actually suggestible by users.  I've given it an upvote.