# Merge or Remove tags [zend-framework1.10], [zend-framework1.8] and [zend-framework1.7]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Please merge or remove the versioned zend-framework tags.
The zend framework minor release version is irrelevant for effectively every question asked.

- [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework) x 6712
- [zend-framework1.10](/questions/tagged/zend-framework1.10) x 10
- [zend-framework1.8](/questions/tagged/zend-framework1.8) x 21
- [zend-framework1.7](/questions/tagged/zend-framework1.7) x 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the questions to remove the version-specific `zend-frameworkX` tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think your counts are off.  I see 6,172 questions in [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework), not only a thousand.

There are only a few dozen questions in the version tags, this could probably be a manual task and nobody would notice the difference.  I've [done this before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85582/remove-zend-merge-into-zend-framework).

Comment: The counts were off because Benjamin was on the Unanswered tab. I've fixed that. At any rate, if it's a small job, that just means that we, the non-mods, can help in this request rather than having to wait for a moderator to step in. ♪