# Zend-ectomy 2.0: Can we get a blacklist / tag synonym this time?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-block-request

[Last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85582/remove-zend-merge-into-zend-framework), I nuked the [zend](/questions/tagged/zend) tag.  Despite watching the new tag list like a *hawk*, it's somehow managed to come back from the dead.

The tag can not stand alone.  Zend is a company.  A VM with their name is what powers PHP ([zend-engine](/questions/tagged/zend-engine)).  They have a PHP certification program ([zend-certification](/questions/tagged/zend-certification)).  They make an IDE ([zend-studio](/questions/tagged/zend-studio)), a web server ([zend-server](/questions/tagged/zend-server), [zend-server-ce](/questions/tagged/zend-server-ce)), a debugger ([zend-debugger](/questions/tagged/zend-debugger)) and a bytecode encryption package ([zend-guard](/questions/tagged/zend-guard)).  They've also leant their name to the Zend Framework ([zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework)).

But there is *nothing* that would be on topic on SO that could *possibly* be called Zend and Zend alone.

The vast majority of the questions tagged [zend](/questions/tagged/zend) are going to be for Zend Framework.  70 of them are co-tagged with it, in fact.  Argh!

While I am going to spend a few days editing all of the ~230 questions into their proper tags, I would really like to get a synonym put in place *or* a blacklist of the tag.  To be clear, the synonym/blacklist shouldn't be done until the questions are already in their proper place, as not *all* of the currently mis-tagged questions belong in [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework).

---

I have now gone through all of the questions tagged [zend](/questions/tagged/zend) and updated the tags on those *not* about Zend Framework.  There were about 25.  There are a few that are about multiple Zend things simultaneously, I've left those alone when one of those things will end up being Zend Framework.  There were about 15 that were tagged [zend](/questions/tagged/zend)+[frameworks](/questions/tagged/frameworks) ("frameworks" having a synonym of "framework") that I've corrected.

Overall, the tagging quality on these questions is pretty abyssmal, but considering that the askers didn't pay enough attention to notice that they were using the wrong tag to begin with, I'm entirely unsurprised.

Comment: `@` ping me when you've sorted this all out and I'll create a synonym. Leave the ones that are intended for `zend-framework` as `zend` and I'll merge them into `zend-framework`. That'll mean a lot less edits and front page bumps.

Comment: @Kev, you'll be my personal hero for doing that one.  I'll let you know when work is complete.

Comment: @Kev, I have completed the minimal retagging work.

Comment: @Charles Great effort. I salute you. (well, upvote you.)

Comment: This reminds me of a post I wrote years ago entitled, [Perl needs Zend](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=579777).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've merged the remaining [zend](/questions/tagged/zend) tags into [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework) and made [zend](/questions/tagged/zend) a synonym of [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework).

Comment: I do agree that the Zend tag on it's own had no real content, but aliasing was just wrong. The framework's proper name is **Zend Framework** or, short, **ZF**. But it is not Zend. Zend is just the company. Before the tag was aliased, I took effort in explaining that in the Zend tag wiki. The wiki also featured the list of available zend-* tags and explicitly stated that the Zend tag was an umbrella tag and people should use one of the more specific zend-* tags instead.

Comment: Granted, people apparently did not read the description so it was likely a useless effort. But the then correct approach would have been to burninate the zend tag altogether. Fortunately, we can still do that. Keeping it aliased will only further spread the incorrect name. It's like aliasing Java to JavaScript.

Comment: @Gordon, between the initial burnination and the creation of the synonym, I destroyed the tag a handful of times after *clueless* users continued to recreate it. I agree that the creation of the synonym is horrifyingly inaccurate, but it matches the modern colloquial understanding of the word "Zend" for almost every person that has (mis)used it. At the very minimum, the synonym maps to the correct tag, which at least tells the user that they've gotten the name wrong. I don't view the war for correct naming to be winnable in this case.  I'd have preferred a blacklist, but I'll take the synonym.

Comment: @Charles I disagree. As long as zend gets mapped to zend-framework they'll think it's a valid synonym, which it is not. Wrong understanding is wrong. Like I said, its like calling JavaScript Java. The only exception is that we could simply ban the Zend tag altogether because it is useless for StackOverflow. And I'd very much prefer that.

Comment: @Gordon I agree, I can also think of other examples e.g mapping `microsoft` to `microsoft-windows` on Super User (actually, that tag needs attention..). You don't want people to be validated in thinking the terms are interchangeable, because for anyone MORE familiar with Microsoft or Zend than their flagship or most prominent product, it'll be confusing and/or unhelpful.