# Please make the JBoss version-specific tags less of a mess

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, ambiguous-tags

This morning, [Ondra Žižka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145989/ondra-zizka) retagged **209** questions from [jboss7.x](/questions/tagged/jboss7.x) to [jboss-as-7](/questions/tagged/jboss-as-7).

While the retag was thorough and *may* be justified<sup>*</sup>, it creates a problem.  *Every other* versioned JBoss tag has been left alone, including:

- [jboss-3.x](/questions/tagged/jboss-3.x), 2 questions
- [jboss-4.0.x](/questions/tagged/jboss-4.0.x), 14 questions
- [jboss-4.2.x](/questions/tagged/jboss-4.2.x), 59 questions
- [jboss-4.3.x](/questions/tagged/jboss-4.3.x), 6 questions
- [jboss5.x](/questions/tagged/jboss5.x), 416 questions
- [jboss6.x](/questions/tagged/jboss6.x), 262 questions

There was already an inconsistency between the wording in the various version-specific tags, but *adding another variation* doesn't help.  Consistency is good.

- If one of the tags is going to be `-as-`'d, then the rest should as well.
- The 5.x and 6.x tags should be hyphenated for consistency regardless.
- We can probably merge 4.0.x, 4.2.x and 4.3.x.  I'm not sure why there's no 4.1.x.

While this is being thought about, it may be wise to revisit the [jboss](/questions/tagged/jboss) tag.  The product name has *always* been "JBoss Application Server."  Common colloquial use of "JBoss" alone has almost always been in reference to the application server.  However, JBoss was a company (now a division of Red Hat) and offered many products.  It is *possibly* inappropriate to continue the use of [jboss](/questions/tagged/jboss) due to the potential confusion it can create between the multitude of JBoss-related projects.  However, I expect that *any* of these tag renames are going to create needless confusion.  Users don't tend to care about product names that include a company name and some entirely uncreative words.  See also, [Zend vs Zend Framework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118732/135887).

<sup>* The retagging seems to have been spawned by a [content dispute](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8991364/revisions) last month, where he deemed the existing tag to be inaccurate, despite colloquial use and tag wikis disagreeing.</sup>

Comment: This should be done through synonyms, if at all.  Hopefully the user is suspended.

Comment: I disagree about a suspension.  The user may not be aware that it should be wise to gain consensus before making such large batches of edits.  I *do* agree that synonyms may be a good solution here.

Comment: After the content dispute? The user's attitude seems to be that they'll foist it upon everyone, unwilling or not. Regardless of their knowledge of process, that should be obviously unacceptable.

Comment: I believe moderators can undo massive retaggings like this? I think that's the appropriate course of action here. If anything is done, a synonym should be created like @Matthew suggests.

Comment: Retagging took me about 15 minutes, no big deal. If you really intend to move it back, I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym has been created, with [jboss7.x](/questions/tagged/jboss7.x) being the master of [jboss-as-7](/questions/tagged/jboss-as-7).

Answer (score 2):

> We can probably merge 4.0.x, 4.2.x and 4.3.x

I disagree with that one. For reasons known only to RedHat, there are very substantial differences between those versions. Advice for one has a very good chance of being inapplicable for the other. Their version numbering at the time was an inconsistent shambles. They sorted it out by the time 5.x came along, though.

> I'm not sure why there's no 4.1.x.

Because there was no JBoss AS 4.1.  See above comment re: shambles.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why "JBoss" was commonly used for the app server is that that was the only project.

Nowadays, JBoss is a brand, a community, or a project supporting group, like is Apache, Codehaus, SourceForge. With over 60 projects, see http://www.jboss.org/projects/matrix .

Would you argue for keeping tags:

- Apache-5.5.x  (for ActiveMQ) ?
- Codehaus-2.x (for Sonar) ?
- SourceForge-1.1.x  (for JDom) ?

No, you would not. This is the same.

StackOverflow has an influence on user's perception of the naming conventions. Why not leveraging that to make the naming habits right? Let's promote the right naming through using jboss-as* tags.

Comment: Okay, sure. But the proper way to do this would be by creating a tag synonym and mapping all of the *existing* tags to a *new* master tag with the correct name. Manually retagging each question is not only a waste of everyone's time, but it comes with other side effects (like "bumping" all the old questions up to the top of the list), and it doesn't prevent the old (incorrectly-named) tags from continuing to be used.

Comment: I fully agree with that.