# Metro tags still a giant mess

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I confess that my hobby of cleaning up the tags on Windows 8 posts has been neglected these last few weeks. And boy, it shows!

First, the new name [metro-framework](/questions/tagged/metro-framework) for the Java web services thing is so not working. Second, someone has made a new [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) tag and about 40 people are using it. I found **multiple** questions tagged [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) [metro-framework](/questions/tagged/metro-framework) which is surely a sign people are confused.

I suggest:

- rename [metro-framework](/questions/tagged/metro-framework) to [java-metro-webservices](/questions/tagged/java-metro-webservices)
- make [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) and [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) synonyms or burninate [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) so people stop using it

I understand that a small handful of people might like to draw a thoughtful distinction between "I am talking about the new design language with tiles, text, and solid blocks of colour, whether implemented on a phone, Windows 8, or just a web site" and "hey doodz this javascript sample code doesn't work when I paste it into my c# app btw I'm totally new to metro ok plz help" but the latter people are cluttering up the tag world and are never going to put much thought into it. We have to make it easy for them to tag their posts. Having one tag for metro in general, and another for specifics of building Windows 8 apps that are fully immersive etc etc is not working.

Comment: The New Tag Deletionist Cabal apologizes for their collective lapse in allowing `metro` to return.  It's been diligently nuked every time it's popped up on the new tag list.  Must have missed a day or something...

Comment: I know, you cannot turn your back on these people for a minute! Expect even more as the reaction to the tablet and to WP8 rises. uh-oh, WP8 and WP7.8 - wonder what those tags look like?

Comment: There's already [tag:surface-tablet] and someone created the annoyingly-named [tag:windowsphone8] tag already.  Nothing about 7.8 yet, give it time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completed.

Use [microsoft-metro](/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro) for questions related to Microsoft's typography-based design language.  [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) and [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) are synonymized to it.

Use [java-metro-framework](/questions/tagged/java-metro-framework) for questions relating to Java's Metro Web Services Framework. [metro-framework](/questions/tagged/metro-framework) is synonymized to it.

When you type "metro" into the tag selector, you will see this:

[image: That was easy.]

Comment: Now yet to fix those "also" links in tag descriptions.

Comment: @Chichiray: Done.

Comment: And now this needs to be [*undone*](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Windows-8-Windows-Phone-Metro-Trademark-Infringement,16606.html#xtor=RSS-998).

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the proposal to synonymize [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) with [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui).

[metro](/questions/tagged/metro) should be **blacklisted**.  The term in itself causes confusion because of ambiguity.  The [last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118732/135887) we tried to associate a vague term with *a* correct answer, it resulted in a great deal of whining and gnashing of teeth.

Blacklisting is *avoiding the issue* and is a bad compromise, but it's probably the only sure-fire way to prevent the ambiguity and cross-community irritation that [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) alone causes.

Comment: What is the ambiguity that you are referring to?

Comment: The Java web service stack is named "Metro."  It was here first, and owned the [tag:metro] tag.  Then Microsoft created a new UI platform called "Metro," which came to dominate the tag.  The two are not the same thing, but they share a name.  The tags were split, but [tag:metro] keeps being recreated, seems like weekly.  [tag:metro] on it's own is vague.

Comment: Then you have to make a decision as to which tag you want to synonymize [metro] to.  I assume there's some sort of [java-metro] tag.  Can we synonymize [metro] to it?

Comment: You can also let people tag questions with [java] [metro], and live with the ambiguity.  Blacklisting tags to solve these kinds of problems is a non-starter; blacklisting is a dev-only function, and should be reserved only for the most egregious tags, like [not-programming-related].

Comment: Right now, the Java thing called Metro is associated with the tag [tag:metro-framework], which is also horribly annoyingly vague.  As noted in the question, people are still using that tag to refer to the Windows technology.  Attaching [tag:metro] to [tag:metro-framework] is going to be a giant step backwards, as users that can't read are going to continue to put Metro UI questions there.

Comment: Then change [metro-framework] to [java-metro], to make it clear that the user is using the wrong tag.

Comment: That is also proposed above, and isn't a bad idea in itself.  I'm just a fan of making sure people can't reasonably do the wrong thing through not thinking.  Preventing [tag:metro] from being a thing is a step in that direction, because it *forces* the user to pay some measure of attention.