# Tagging for Metro (Windows 8): new modern-ui tag causes confusion

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I'm a bit concerned about the tags on Stack Overflow. I think that the tag [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) should be merged to [modern-ui](/questions/tagged/modern-ui), and in fact, [modern-ui](/questions/tagged/modern-ui) should be the master.

I do not have any privileges to do this (neither has ANYONE, the synonym needs five upvotes in the topic. The maximum any person has is one). I think this should be done because Metro has gone out of favour with MS, due to the [Metro AG issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_AG#Recent_news), and they have renamed it to Modern. I think Stack Overflow should reflect this as well.

Comment: this needed a catchier title. I'm following the whole metro/win8/winrt/no-that-other-winrt/windows-store-apps misery and almost missed this one

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158900/sorry-again-windows-8-metro-etc http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137135/metro-tags-still-a-giant-mess http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125890/is-tag-sponsorship-contributing-to-confusion-between-metro-and-metro-ui http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106716/windows-8-and-related-tags-need-a-little-love and many more

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Considering that [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) has ~2000 questions, and [modern-ui](/questions/tagged/modern-ui) has *2*, I think the community has already decided. Anyway, whatever MSFT wants to name it, modern-ui is very ambiguous. It could just mean designing something in a modern way, or updating Windows 2000 software to a later design metaphor. If we're going to switch, at least make it [microsoft-modern-ui](/questions/tagged/microsoft-modern-ui), and leave a note telling about the switch.

Comment: Agreed it should be metro-ui. The change was made for BS legal reasons that don't concern anyone but MS. Metro is recognizable

Comment: @BenBrocka: Exactly! Thanks.

Comment: "Modern-UI" is going to become ambiguous when Windows 9 appears.

Comment: @DourHighArch: That too.