# Ambiguous tag [virtual]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

The [virtual](/questions/tagged/virtual) tag has the very vague tag wiki:

> An extensible or simulated artifact.

Questions with this tag usually refer to [virtual-functions](/questions/tagged/virtual-functions) [virtual-machine](/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) or [virtualization](/questions/tagged/virtualization)

Also questions tagged with [virtual](/questions/tagged/virtual)[destructor](/questions/tagged/destructor) should be tagged [virtual-destructor](/questions/tagged/virtual-destructor)

I think these questions should be re-tagged.

Comment: I definitely agree it shouldn't exist - but 1556 questions is not a small number. [It is a very big number!](http://www.homestarrunner.com/sbemail118.html), which will take quite a lot of combined work. Does it make any sense to just BURNiNATE & blacklist the tag outright? I'd assume that anything tagged "virtual" would have more pertinent information in the post body, (which can be found via searching).

Comment: 1500 is non-trivial, but [it's been done before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85115/135887).  Hell, we've done [5k+](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160216/1358870) before.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why you were going through and retagging a large number of these. People have been flagging some of these edits, such as these: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2467061 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2467073 because they didn't know why it was being removed. Have we reached a consensus that this tag needs to be removed everywhere? While broad, it does seem to fit with some of these questions about the "virtual" keyword, etc.